# How to remove all preinstalled apps instead of the ones needed by the system?

Tags: 20.04

Is this possible? Im trying to remove all software that comes preinstalled instead of the Settings app, Terminal and GNOME. If it is possible, how can I do this? (Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: Would probably be easier to start over with a minimal install of Ubuntu and add what you want.  Most pre install apps should be able to be removed, but a few might tied into the system itself and would cause problems if removed.

Comment: Where can I get that? (The minimal install)

Comment: It should be at Ubuntu com, but probably under alternative/other downloads.

Comment: Not quite sure this is a duplicate.  The OP asked how to remove all pre-install apps.  I just thought a minimal install would be easier and not cause problems with removing the wrong app.